# Как уменшить количество данных для расчета процентиля?

Tags: алгоритм

Допустим есть измерения скорости ветра в 1000 городов за каждую секунду.
Задача посчитать 99 процентиль для каждого города за последние 7 дней.
Все данные надо хранить в оперативной памяти.
Существует ли какой-то качественный алгоритм, чтобы сократить объём данных?
Если бы надо было считать среднее, а не процентиль, мы могли бы считать среднее по каждому часу, а потом брать среднее от этих средних, и не было бы ни какой потери точности. Часы которые уже стали старее чем 7 дней мы бы выкидывали из оперативки.
С процентилем так не работает. Процентиль от процентиля даёт уже другой результат, искажая в большую сторону.

Chat GPT выдал что есть два метода: R-Block Method и Quantile Replacement Method. Очень мало инфы по этим методам в Google, но как я добился от бота:

R-Block method это разбиение на блоки с экспонциально растущим размером, в каждом блоке считается процентиль, а потом берётся линейная интерполяция, я не понял для чего именно, но в моём случае вся интерполяция сводится к взятию среднего арифметического от этих процентилей в этих блоках.

Это мне не очень подходит, так как экспонциальный размер блока не применим на первый взгляд к этой задаче, а на блоках равного размера, я не почувствовал, что результат близок к правде.

Quantile Replacement Method по объяснению бота, это разбить на блоки, взять среднее по каждому, и от этих средних посчитать процентиль. В ходе эксперимента этот подход показал самый худший результат с сильно уменьшенным результатом.

Comment: А точность какая требуется? Например, если точность в 1 м/с, то я бы просто сделал массив на 500 элементов, от -250 до +250 м/с, и туда вносил бы счетчики каждого  измерения. Если я верно понял описание процентиля на Вики, то из массива счетчиков + знания суммарного количества измерений, можно вывести эти процентили. Если точность нужна до 2 знаков после запятой, то это будет массив на 50000 значений, что тоже не особо много. Если прямо точно-точно надо, то подсчет не подойдет конечно

Comment: мне нравится ваш вариант, я тоже такое думал, но отбросил так как показалось не очень компактно, вспоминая что для каждого города будет свой массив. Но в конце концов, компактность можно настраивать меняя длительность блока.

Comment: `3600*24*7 *1000 < 1.e9` У вас вообще все данные помещаются в память. В чем проблема с  повторными проходами по массиву данных?

Comment: @Chorkov нужно потратить меньше памяти.

Comment: Вообще можно посмотреть, сколько уникальных значений есть за день. Может и не нужно ничего округлять будет. Может словаря за день вида скорость:количество будет достаточно для экономии места. Ну или если не хватит, то пробовать округлять до стольки разрядов, чтобы хватило. А к чему вы стремитесь, не более скольки памяти вам нужно резервировать под задачу? Может можете куда-то пример данных выложить хотя бы за день?

Comment: Здесь: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1407.1121.pdf  (раздел 6) есть небольшой обзор алгоритмов вычисления процентиля. Подозреваю, что GPT свои  названия методов просто выдумал.

Comment: С какой точностью измеряется скорость ветра?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, доподлинно неизвестно ну и не так уж важно. Можем округлить так что бы оставить только сотню возможных значений.

Comment: Храните для каждого часа гистограмму для "сотни возможных значений". По таким гистограммам процентиль восстанавливается точно. См. первый комментарий.